# IXMLHTTPRequest2 Set-Cookie Header with HttpOnly flag - Windows Phone 8

Tags: windows-phone-8

I am working on a Win Phone 8 C++ application that is using IXMLHTTPRequest2 to perform HTTP requests. During one part of the request, I need to get out the Cookie values from a server that has the HttpOnly flag set.

Is there any way that I can get access to that header in this case?

```
WCHAR* pBuf = NULL;
HRESULT hr = m_xhr->GetResponseHeader(L"Set-Cookie", &pBuf);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't due to a security feature of these cookies. HttpOnly cookies can't be accessed from the client code (e.g. your C++ or Javascript or C#), only from the server.